# когда нажимаю sumbit вылазит ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

tk['bg'] = 'white'
tk.title('flappy bird')
tk.geometry('800x600+400+100')

tk.resizable(False, False)

def get():
    label1['text'] = name.get()


tx = Label(tk, text='Имя:  ', font=('Arial 20')).grid(row=0, column=0)
name = Entry(tk, font='Arial 20').grid(row=0, column=1)
btn = Button(tk, text='Sumbit', font='Arial 20', command=get).grid(row=2, column=0)
label1 = Label(tk, bg='black', fg='white')
label1.grid(row=3, column=1)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно писать в две команды:

```
name = Entry(tk, font='Arial 20')
name.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

А то у вас переменная `name` получала значение которое возвращает метод `grid()`, а он всегда возвращает `None`.

*P.S. Для `Label` же вы при этом правильно написали...*